# PPTP VPN error: LCP terminated by peer

Tags: authentication, vpn, pptp

I cannot connect to my PPTP VPN server, even though the CHAP authentication succeeds.

This is from /var/log/syslog:

```
Jun 11 07:27:22 aspire pppd[32221]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jun 11 07:27:22 aspire pppd[32221]: LCP terminated by peer (MPPE required but cannot negotiate MPPE key length)
Jun 11 07:27:22 aspire pptp[32232]: nm-pptp-service-32219 log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer, I had to enable Point-to-Point encryption(MPPE) in the Advanced Settings dialog. Now it works.

[image]